# meta refresh to redirect to HTTPS

Tags: html, redirect, nginx, https

/index.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<title>............</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://www......./subfolder/">
</head>
</html>
```

If you visit the "hostname", you get redirected to **HTTP version** of the website, if you visit the *hostname/index.htm*, you get redirected to the **HTTPS version** of the website.

Why does this happen?

Edit: view-source:*hostname/* shows the old content, with http instead of https. However I can't find this in **ANY** file on the server and there is no other index. What else can "rewrite" /? Maybe some web server config file? The web is running nginx and there is no .htaccess in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

Because the two different URLs get different responses from the webserver.

`/index.htm` gets the document you included in the question.

`/` gets something else. Possibly a file called `index.html`.